# No Primes list Comprehension

Tags: python

Trying to get my head around list comprehensions, and dealing with list in list operations in python.

From this guide http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk I cannot quite figure out what is happening in the first line.

```
>>> noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
>>> primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
>>> print primes
[2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
```

So I have put the line into pythontutor to visualize it. So I can see that for each value of i , j it goes (2,4) (2,6) (2, 8) then (3,6) (3, 9) (3, 12) etc But I cannot understand in a sentence exactly what is happening.

Getting list to work for me is my big stumbling block in getting highly useful, I just can't get it to gel, it's just not "reading" clearly to me.

Comment: That's a fancy one-liner for the Sieve of Eratosthenes http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The line

```
noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
```

is equivalent to:

```
noprimes = []
for i in range(2,8):
   for j in range(i*2, 50, i):
     noprimes.append(j)
```

and the line

```
primes = [x for x in range(2, 50) if x not in noprimes]
```

is equivalent to:

```
primes=[]
for x in range(2,50): 
  if x not in noprimes: 
    primes.append(x)
```

**Update, in response to comment**

The lines

```
   for j in range(i*2, 50, i):
     noprimes.append(j)
```

generate a sequence of numbers. The starting number is `2*i`, the increment is `i`, and the sequence stops before it reaches or exceeds `50`.

When `i = 2`, it generates the sequence of numbers `4 6 8 ... 48`

When `i = 3`, it generates the sequence of numbers `6 9 12 ... 48`

etc.

The entire loop generates the following numbers

```
4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 32, 34, 36, 38, 40, 42, 44, 46, 48,
6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36, 39, 42, 45, 48,
8, 12, 16, 20, 24, 28, 32, 36, 40, 44, 48,
10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45,
12, 18, 24, 30, 36, 42, 48,
14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49
```

Comment: j in range(i*2, 50, i) so what is exactly happening what is j finding.

Answer (score 1):

```
noprimes = [j for i in range(2, 8) for j in range(i*2, 50, i)]
```

This is equivalent to the following:

```
noprimes = []
for i in range(2, 8):
    for j in range(i*2, 50, i):
        noprimes.append(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

First it constructs `noprimes`, which is a list of composite numbers.
`i` ranges from 2 to 7. When `i` is 2, `j` iterates through 4, 6, 8,
etc.; multiples of 2, but excluding 2. When `i` is 3, `j` is 6, 9, 12,
etc. So `noprimes` ends up containing all the composite numbers up to 49
(some of them, multiple times).

Then `primes` just takes all the numbers from 2 to 49 that aren't in
`noprimes`.